# Style of span inside span doesn't work

Tags: css, transform, html

I have HTML code:

```
<div>
    <span>e</span>
    <span id="transform">w</span>
    <span>q</span>
</div>
```

and a CSS:

```
#transform{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

and the letter 'w' looks flipped vertically. That is correct. But when I wrap spans with spans:

```
<div>
    <span>
        <span>e</span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span id="transform">w</span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <span>q</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

And the letter doesn't look flipped, it means my css doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the display value to `block` - as a `<span>` element is inline by default and the `transform` property only applies to [*transformable elements*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-transforms-20120228/#TermTransformableElement) (block-level and atomic-level inline elements)

```css
#transform{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
     transform: rotate(180deg);
     display: block;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a7EXc/

Answer (score 1):

To use `transform` on an element, the element must have some sort of block-like display, such as `display: block` or `display: inline-block`.

The most appropriate fix here is:

```css
#transform {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Everything will look the same, except your letter will be flipped.